# Flutter build fails on android emulator

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

The build of my flutter app fails since I installed new java 17 version.

I already updated `JAVA_HOME` and the gradle user home in Android Studio.

This is how my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file looks like

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip
```

This is the error message I got:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':cloud_firestore:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
     Required by:
         project :cloud_firestore
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6.1' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':cloud_firestore' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':cloud_firestore' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make this check :

change Gradle JDK to a version that is compatible with your new upgrade.

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Once it is done it is recommended to make :

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart